# ArrayList Problem in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, arraylist

i have problem LINQ query.In above,i got error system.object cant be converted to Sytem.String. What can be the problem?

if i use string() instead of ArrayList, it doesn't raise error. But in String(), i should add items manually

```
Public Shared Function GetCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
     Dim movies As New ArrayList()
        Dim dt As DataTable = StaticData.Get_Data(StaticData.Tables.LU_TAG)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            movies.Add(row.Item("DS_TAG"))
        Next
     Return (From m In movies _
             Where m.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) _
             Select m).Take(count).ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, do not *ever* use `ArrayList` or any of the other types in `System.Collections`. These types are deprecated in favour of their generic equivalents (if available) in the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`. The equivalent of `ArrayList` happens to be `List(Of T)`.

Secondly, returning an array from a method is generally considered bad practice – although even methods from the framework do this (but this is now widely considered a mistake). Instead, return either `IEnumerable(Of T)` or `IList(Of T)`, that is: use an interface instead of a concrete type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and do:

```
return dt
    .AsEnumerable() // sic!
    .Select(r => r.Item("DS_TAG")) // DataTable becomes IEnumrable<DataRow>
    .Where(m => m.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();
```

(sorry but that's C# syntax, rewrite to VB.NET as you need)